# how long does an ad from admob need to be visible to count as impression

Tags: android, admob

Google and admob policies are quite vague and hard to decifrate....
According to admob faq:

> An impression is counted when at least 1 pixel of an ad is visible on
>   a device's screen.

So it tells me that if the add is partially under something else at the layout it should still count as impression (great)

but how long does it need to be visible?

I've an pop up that comes on every loading screen in my app and this pop up contains a huge banner... the pop up goes invisible as soon as the app finished to load what it needed...

The question is: if it just displayed for 1 seconds or so, will admob still count as an impression?

Comment: I think it just has to be displayed: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6168758?hl=en

Comment: Keep in mind that even if it counts as an impression, you won't get any income from them because nobody could click your single-pixel ad.

Comment: @JohannesJ, you doesn't necessary need to get a click in order to get income

Comment: From my experience eCPM is calculated based on the click revenue you have generated per thousand impressions. I did sometimes have clicks rendered invalid (Google tends to do that) but not all income was deducted, so you would have a very small amount of income but no clicks. Regardless, the income you would get from impressions alone, based on that, is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers are exactly true;
If you display the banner you will get income. No need to get click. But if your click per impression on your page/app is low; then you will get really cheap ads instead of expensive ads so you will be punished. So even if you show 100X more banner you can get 10X lower income.